# angular.js - headers error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post

This code throws SyntaxError: Unexpected token W. Why? And how to fix it?

```
      http({
          method: 'POST',          
          url: defaultUrl,
          data: $.param(newPlayer),.
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      })
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: There was bug in rest code, but now it is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be a dot after data. and "`" at the end.
here it goes.

```
 http({
          method: 'POST',          
          url: defaultUrl,
          data: $.param(newPlayer),
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
      })
```